# Drupal 7 shared cloud hosting problem

Tags: web-hosting, drupal, cloud

I'm hosting one drupal 7 website on site5.com cloud shared hosting and it seems to be that drupal cache queries go very slow on almost every table that starts with name cache_...

This site is using 1-2 custom modules, i18 module only for front page text, about 13 custom types fields and has about 650 nodes. Now site has been used only me and my client.

I contact hosting and they say that problem aren't their, but I have been thinking, I have one drupal 7 site, with webshop in croatia with 7000 nodes and active 30 users per seconds on poor host and everything is going well.

My questions are, it can be something with a new drupal 7 update (7,19) or my website is really that slow (highly doubt) or cloud shared hosting is only a cheap trick from site5.com?

Answer (score 2):

I always suggest my clients to go with VPS or Dedicated Servers when dealing with Drupal since it has the power to eat up your server resources in no time and with a few mistakes.

Here the problem looks like its a fault of your server. If you are using apache then i suggest use a reverse proxy with nginx and or varnish cache to help your server breathe easy if that is possible on your shared hosting plan. Same to go with if you are gonna work in a VPS or dedicated server.

Comment: Thx for answer, I get VPS, now I'm learninn about cache solustion, what about memcache?

Comment: memcache is good too but it will require a lot of testings and lot of understanding of its core features whereas with varnish you can get started immediately. Drupal supports varnish in its core so you will be in good hands.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say exactly what the problem with the given information but with what you have lead to say its most likely a hosting problem.

**Shared Resources and Fixed Limits**

The problem with shared hosting is that various web host providers will run there shared hosting differently, it sounds to me that site5 has set max resources on their shared accounts meaning your only assigned a certain amount of CPU time meaning that it will slow down on medium to heavy tasks.

**Take GoDaddy as an Example**

The reason I say this is that I have many shared accounts off over the globe with about 12 different shared hosting companies, naming one of them GoDaddy I am assigned fixed resources and my site really slows down if I purge some of the SQL - in fact all of the other GoDaddy hosted sites slow down at the same time which proves that they are restricting the amount of resources I have and even in there terms it says 'UNLIMITED SITES*' which mentions that each site I add will have the same shared resources so effectively the more sites I add the slower it gets as the usage goes higher, however on other shared hosting accounts this isn't the case and they just share the whole resources across every website on it, this means you get burst but also means that if some sites are heavy you effectively can be slowed down because of them so its a win lose situation.

**Consider VPS Hosting**

VPS servers are really cheap these days and much faster than shared hosting, in some cases VPS can be cheaper, Take OpenVZ for example these tend to be the cheapest.

I recommend you take a look at VPS Clouds, Xen, OpenVZ, and KVM and pick one you feel is in your budget and requirements.

Once you go VPS you won't go back.

Comment: Thank you @bybe very much for this long answer I start to looking VPS for my testing enviroment, now I only must see what hosting to proposal my client.